# About the life of transient attributes in entity of core data

Tags: core-data, transient

I has a question that.
I need a runtime attribute in MyEntity, it is changed very offen.
And there are many MyEntity in core data.(such as 1000,0000);
I know that the transient attribute wont be saved in the disk, so these 1000,0000 MyEntities must be in memory all the time? but there are so many MyEntites,
the memory is large enough to keep 1000,0000 MyEntities?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change values on a large number of objects, those objects must exist. This is true whether or not you're using Core Data.

With Core Data there are various options for keeping memory under control-- getting rid of individual objects by re-faulting them, or getting rid of all managed objects by resetting the managed object context, for example. But it's hard to tell what you're really trying to do here and why any of this is needed. If this attribute is transient, why would you want to change it on an object that you're not using, that's not even loaded into memory? You could load the object, change the transient value, and then get rid of the object to keep memory use under control. But since the transient attribute doesn't get saved, what's the point? When you're done, nothing has changed. Why not just skip the update completely?